# If a boy was tattooed on his back, would the tattoo more-or-less sruvive into adulthood intact?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, humans, children

If a child, say, a white, ten year old boy, got a **big** tattoo on his upper back (read: shoulder to shoulder), would it change a lot as the child grew into adulthood?

Since the early-ish industrial society suffers a distinct lack of tattoo machines, the application of this tattoo would therefore need to be applied by traditional means (either by inserting pigments (e.g. coal, ashes) into open wounds, or with the help of "needles" from animal bones/sticks/whatever (edit: or metal needles, as user Dewi Morgan pointed out, thank you), not sure how much that influences the answer.

> Ideally, it would change as little as possible, or with minor breaks, tears, etc., that could be solved by a later retouching.

### Possible problems

- As the back gets bigger, the skin needs to get bigger as well - it needs to grow *somehow, somewhere*.

  - Would it move around and "travel" like smaller scars do? To where? How far?
  - Would it simply stretch and get bigger, or stretch *and* tear, as new patches of skin get build inside of the tattooed area?

Optional questions: What about the colour?

- I assume it will fade, as all tattoos do, correct me if I'm wrong, - though I'm not sure how it works coupled with the wound coloring.
- Any ideas if it would change colour? Ink gets green, since the black is made from it, but natural black pigments tend to be black if I'm not mistaken?

This tatoo should be a part of a child's rite of passage of a culture that currently lives in alpine-like mountains. Is it viable? If the tattoo gets derpy, skewed, or changes too much, it would not make sense and therefore can't be a part of the ritual.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Exchange. This isn't really a worldbuilding question, since you're asking a question about something that's happening right now in the real world, rather than a world building question. As far as your question goes, have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschko%27s_lines

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour]. Please provide more specific information because, not surprisingly, all skin is not made the same.  Which human race are we talking about?  Boy or girl?  Exactly what age did they get the tattoo? What specific year should we use for technology assessment?  Are we to use the best tech of the day, or "prison tech?"  How complex is the tatoo?  How fine are the lines?

Comment: 19th century was well into the industrial revolution, and had advanced far beyond the "animal bones/sticks/whatever" stage, though electric tattoo guns were only invented towards the end of the century. Ötzi, a mummy from ~6,000 years ago, had tattoos that might've been made that way, but metal pins for tattoos go back to the Egyptians and copts. Metal pins are less likely to have their tips snap in flesh, and also mean that you could have multiple pins on the end of the tool, making the process faster. Egyptian and coptic tools tended to have odd numbers of metal pins.

Comment: Definitely Google the history of tattooing in the area you are interested in, as the styles will be radically different (monochrome, brightly colored, etc), as will the tools to make them, depending where and when you're writing about. The pigments will fade, and will stretch as expected over the back rather than splitting, but I know too little to give more good details. There unfortunately does not seem to be a good StackExchange for this kind of question, but Quora.com may be a good fit? It has question categories for "body art", "tattoos", etc.

Comment: Why was this question closed?  The [help/on-topic] states, "World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world."  The old Help center explained that the affects of technology on a culture was also on-topic (is that no longer the case?)  Can any of the close voters explain why they think this is OT:NAW?  I'm going to VTR.

Comment: Also, please remember that a VTC is NOT a super-downvote.  If the question lacks research, that's a reason to downvote, not close.

Comment: Oh, I guess I see where you guys are coming from! Thanks for the answers anyways. I should have probably specified but it _is_ a world building question, since the tattoo should be a part of a rite of passage, during which children are pledged to a god and those from certain parts of the social hiearchy get a symbol of said god tattooed. The reason why I'm asking is, because I want to know if it makes sense. Should the tattoo more or less stay the same, it does - later in adulthood it can be renewed as needed. If it changes a lot and weirdly, it does not and cannot be a part of the rite.

Comment: Hi weirdflexbutiamconfusion, unfortunately the edit that you've just made really doesn't help make the question any less off-topic. Please follow JBH's advice, and when you have time read the [help].

Comment: Hey! I did actually read the help center and I am unsure as to why it would still be placed off topic, since this question does, in fact, relate to world building, specifically a ritual aspect of a culture. I did some research on this topic already, but my answers tapped into areas of more practical and concrete problems, than historical literature would cover, especially since tattooing children is illegal. I am not trying to be rude, or anything, but understanding your reasoning would help me as a reference for future questions.